# Convert Json string to Json object in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift

I try to convert JSON string to a JSON object but after `JSONSerialization` the output is `nil` in JSON.

Response String:

```
[{\"form_id\":3465,\"canonical_name\":\"df_SAWERQ\",\"form_name\":\"Activity 4 with Images\",\"form_desc\":null}]
```

I try to convert this string with my code below:

```
let jsonString = response.result.value
let data: Data? = jsonString?.data(using: .utf8)
let json = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])) as? [String:AnyObject]
 print(json ?? "Empty Data")
```

Comment: did you added the alamofire  pod.  https://www.google.com/search?ei=968KWufnFcvWvgS7rKW4BA&q=alamofire+swift+4&oq=alamofire&gs_l=psy-ab.1.2.0i71k1l4.0.0.0.19859.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1..64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.w_2p_WJHPH4

Comment: Yes I installed  Alamofire Pod

Comment: Use a `do ... catch` instead and print the error. It'll probably tell you what's wrong.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

The problem is that you thought your jsonString is a dictionary. It's not.

It's an **array** of dictionaries. 
In raw json strings, arrays begin with `[` and dictionaries begin with `{`.

---

I used your json string with below code :

```
let string = "[{\"form_id\":3465,\"canonical_name\":\"df_SAWERQ\",\"form_name\":\"Activity 4 with Images\",\"form_desc\":null}]"
let data = string.data(using: .utf8)!
do {
    if let jsonArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options : .allowFragments) as? [Dictionary<String,Any>]
    {
       print(jsonArray) // use the json here     
    } else {
        print("bad json")
    }
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error)
}
```

and I am getting the output :

```
[["form_desc": <null>, "form_name": Activity 4 with Images, "canonical_name": df_SAWERQ, "form_id": 3465]]
```

Comment: How we get the value from "jsonArray".  I am trying                         if let name = jsonArray["name"] as? String {
                            // no error
                        }
which is giving the error "Cannot subscript a value of type '[Dictionary<String, Any>]' with an index of type 'String'"

Comment: @Androidiseverythingforme : That's an array of dictionary, try `let form_name = jsonArray[0]["form_name"] as? String` and you will get the output.

Comment: this was the solution for me too , i was getting a raw json from url , and was unable to read it as an array because it was a string; so the line : " let data = string.data(using: .utf8)! " mentionned in this solution was what solved it , Thank you sir

Answer (score 41):

Using `JSONSerialization` always felt unSwifty and unwieldy, but it is even more so with the arrival of `Codable` in Swift 4. If you wield a `[String:Any]` in front of a simple `struct` it will ... hurt. Check out this in a Playground:

```
import Cocoa

let data = "[{\"form_id\":3465,\"canonical_name\":\"df_SAWERQ\",\"form_name\":\"Activity 4 with Images\",\"form_desc\":null}]".data(using: .utf8)!

struct Form: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let description: String?

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "form_id"
        case name = "form_name"
        case description = "form_desc"
    }
}

do {
    let f = try JSONDecoder().decode([Form].self, from: data)
    print(f)
    print(f[0])
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

With minimal effort handling this will feel a whole lot more comfortable. *And* you are given a lot more information if your JSON does not parse properly.

Comment: am I the only one who gets "Type 'Form' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'" ?

Comment: You would have to post your code (in another question, not a comment, there it will look horrible) and your Swift version in order for anyone to help.

Comment: remove "import Cocoa" for Swift 5 then it works. thanks!

Answer (score 17):

I tried the solutions here, and **as? [String:AnyObject]** worked for me:

```
do{
    if let json = stringToParse.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8){
        if let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: json, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:AnyObject]{
            let id = jsonData["id"] as! String
            ...
        }
    }
}catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)

}
```

Comment: `id` is nil for me.

Answer (score 8):

**I used below code and it's working fine for me. :**

```
let jsonText = "{\"userName\":\"Bhavsang\"}"
var dictonary:NSDictionary?
    
if let data = jsonText.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
        
     do {
            dictonary =  try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: [.allowFragments]) as? [String:AnyObject]
        
            if let myDictionary = dictonary
              {
                  print(" User name is: \(myDictionary["userName"]!)")
              }
            } catch let error as NSError {
            
            print(error)
         }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
static func getJSONStringFromObject(object: Any?) -> String? {
    do {
        let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: object ?? DUMMY_STRING, options: [])
        return String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8) ?? DUMMY_STRING
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    return DUMMY_STRING
}
```

Comment: this does the oposite from what OP wants