# How to Dictionary to JSON string and JSON String to Dictionary From alamofire/swiftyJson in iOS swift

Tags: swift

Dictionary to Convert Json String

```
let dictionary = ["nacho": ["1","2","3"]]
let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dictionary, options: [])
let jsonString = String(data: jsonData!, encoding: .utf8)
print(jsonString)
```

Json String Convert to Dictionary

```
let jsonString = "{\"nacho\":[\"1\",\"2\",\"3\"]}"
let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)
let dictionary = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData!, options: .mutableLeaves)
print(dictionary!)
```

Comment: this code not working Alamofire and SwiftJson

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47281375/convert-json-string-to-json-object-in-swift-4/47281832#47281832

Comment: not work ..direct NSError print @Amit

Comment: Alamofire/SwiftJson liberty to set getter and setter method to dict to string and string to dict @Amit

Comment: You cant convert dictionary to JSON! if you want to manually build json, do something like this:                 let myJSON = JSON(); myJSON["aaa"] = "aaa"

Answer (score 0):

Another instance where the giant ant hits you with the curse of the evil `JSONSerialization`. You have much more control on the serialisation process if you go the slightly more verbose way of the `Codable` protocol, but the result will be much easier to handle. Put the following into a quick Playground to see the difference:

```
import Cocoa

let dictionary = ["nacho": ["1","2","3"]]
let jsonDt = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dictionary, options: [])
let jsonString = String(data: jsonDt!, encoding: .utf8)!
print(jsonString)

let jsonStr = "{\"nacho\":[\"1\",\"2\",\"3\"]}"
let jsonDat = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)
let dict = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonDat!, options: .mutableLeaves)
print(dict!)

struct Chips: Codable {
    let nacho: [Int]
}

let chip = Chips(nacho: [1, 2, 3])
print(chip)

let chipData: Data?
do {
    chipData = try JSONEncoder().encode(chip)
    print(String(data:chipData!, encoding:.utf8)!)
} catch {
    print(error)
    chipData = nil
}

if let chipData = chipData {
    do {
        let chips = try JSONDecoder().decode(Chips.self, from: chipData)
        print(chips)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

As you have seen the strings in the first serialisation/deserialization cycle end up being `Ints` (which I suspect they should have been in the first place), even when they used to be `String`. `JSONSerialization.jsonObject` seems to have a mind of its own about which types you will be getting.

In my definition of `Chips` (for lack of a better name) I could force the use of `[Int]` which seems more clean. Try out the effect of changing this definition to `String`. You will have to adapt the initialisation of the object and the serialised `String` will of course reflect the change. The big advantage over your initial solution with `JSONSerialization` consists in getting a consistent `encode`/`decode` cycle *either way*, of course with slightly different properties. Choose your preferred way and I am sure your `Alamofire` will be happy to work with either.

Comment: @BhavikAntala It would be customary (and earn you some points the first time you do) to accept an answer if it solved your problem. Otherwise please post a comment asking for clarification.

Comment: Alamofire/swiftJson UserDetail Dictionary Response Convert string to store (Data Setter)                                                                                 func setUserDetail(_ UserDetail: String?) {
        let personEncodedObject = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: UserDetail!)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(personEncodedObject, forKey: "UserDetail")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }  - data setter complete @patru

Comment: but string to Dictinary data not Convert. This is code not work                                               static func userDetail() -> String? {
        var UserDetail: String? = nil
        let arcData = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "UserDetail")
        UserDetail = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: arcData as! Data) as? String
        return UserDetail
    }    -  @Patru

Comment: Two things are bad style here, first of all you should _not_ put code into comments if it is more than one line, move it to a question. Second your comments do not have anything to do with your initial question. Please ask a different one. You will have more space and improved formatting options to explain what you want to do and why it does not work and, frankly speaking, this is sadly needed.