# JSONSerialization.jsonObject returns nil

Tags: ios, swift, jsonserializer

```
var responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
var responseDict: [AnyHashable : Any]? = nil
if let anEncoding = responseString?.data(using: String.Encoding(rawValue: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)) {
   responseDict = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: anEncoding, options: .mutableContainers) as? [AnyHashable : Any]
}
```

**responseString** is coming out to be :

> [{\"message_id\":1916,\"in_app\":{\"primary_color\":\"#333333\",\"secondary_color\":\"#ffffff\",\"position\":\"0\",\"duration\":\"30\",\"expiry\":\"2018-11-07T23:17:46.169-05:00\",\"delay_minute\":\"0\",\"delay_second\":\"0\",\"message\":\"This
>   is what your message will look like! Type in your message in the text
>   area and get a preview right
>   here\",\"data\":{},\"deeplinkurl\":\"\",\"attachment-url\":\"\",\"title\":\"\",\"subtitle\":\"\"}},{\"message_id\":1920,\"in_app\":{\"primary_color\":\"#333333\",\"secondary_color\":\"#ffffff\",\"position\":\"0\",\"duration\":\"30\",\"expiry\":\"2018-11-08T03:52:15.404-05:00\",\"delay_minute\":\"0\",\"delay_second\":\"0\",\"message\":\"This
>   is what your message will look like! Type in your message in the text
>   area and get a preview right
>   here\",\"data\":{},\"deeplinkurl\":\"\",\"attachment-url\":\"\",\"title\":\"\",\"subtitle\":\"\"}}]

**responseDict** is coming out to be `nil`.
The corresponding `Objective-C` code was working just fine.

Comment: If your using Swift 4 it would be much better to use the `Codable` protocol

Comment: That's because `[AnyHashable : Any]` is a Dictionary but your JSON is a Array at top level. Also, avoid `.mutableContainers` with Swift Dictionaries/Array. And `String.Encoding(rawValue: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)` => `.utf8` or `String.Encoding.utf8`. should be enough.

Comment: @Larme you should post that as an answer

Comment: @Scriptable There are so much questions about JSON parsing in Swift/Objective-C, there should at least have one duplicate because author didn't see the top level type of the response.

Comment: why is your variable called `anEncoding` if it is **not** an encoding?

Comment: yeah true.. I'll have a look

Comment: `if let anEncoding = responseString?.data(using: String.Encoding(rawValue: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue))` is horrible. `Data` created from an UTF8 string can never be `nil`. Replace it with `let data = Data(responseString!.utf8)` (without `if`)

Comment: Also to note: using `try!` will not catch the error, it will most likely crash. If you use a do catch statement you can print the error and it will point you to the issue... and prevent a crash

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47281375/convert-json-string-to-json-object-in-swift-4/47281832#47281832

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works fine…

```
let json = """
[{\"message_id\":1916,\"in_app\":{\"primary_color\":\"#333333\",\"secondary_color\":\"#ffffff\",\"position\":\"0\",\"duration\":\"30\",\"expiry\":\"2018-11-07T23:17:46.169-05:00\",\"delay_minute\":\"0\",\"delay_second\":\"0\",\"message\":\"This is what your message will look like! Type in your message in the text area and get a preview right here\",\"data\":{},\"deeplinkurl\":\"\",\"attachment-url\":\"\",\"title\":\"\",\"subtitle\":\"\"}},{\"message_id\":1920,\"in_app\":{\"primary_color\":\"#333333\",\"secondary_color\":\"#ffffff\",\"position\":\"0\",\"duration\":\"30\",\"expiry\":\"2018-11-08T03:52:15.404-05:00\",\"delay_minute\":\"0\",\"delay_second\":\"0\",\"message\":\"This is what your message will look like! Type in your message in the text area and get a preview right here\",\"data\":{},\"deeplinkurl\":\"\",\"attachment-url\":\"\",\"title\":\"\",\"subtitle\":\"\"}}]
""".data(using: .utf8)!

do {
    let object = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: json, options: [])
    print(object)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

… but don't use `JSONSerialization`… declare custom objects that represent your data and use `Decodable` instead

Comment: Note that the solution works because of the absence of the `as? Dictionary` contrary the code in the question. `as? [[String: Any]]` should have work too.