# Getting null value when parsing string value from json iOS swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am getting a json from my server. my server json is

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    print(userInfo)
 }
```

this print result of userInfo

```
[AnyHashable("smallIcon"): small_icon, AnyHashable("tickerText"): , AnyHashable("message"): {"action":"new_content_notification","msg":{"headline":"iOS REFERRAL BONUS","subhead":"Congratulations. You have unlocked another BDT500 discount on long route trip booking.","brief":"Congratulations. You have unlocked another BDT500 discount on long route trip booking.","content_id":44}}, AnyHashable("subtitle"): www.ezzyr.com, AnyHashable("sound"): 1, AnyHashable("gcm.message_id"): 0:id, AnyHashable("aps"): {
   "content-available" = 1;     
},
AnyHashable("title"): Notification from ezzyr, AnyHashable("vibrate"): 1, AnyHashable("largeIcon"): large_icon]
```

i am converting this by using swifty json. after converting swity json i am gettng this

```
let fullInfo = JSON(userInfo)
print(fullInfo)

{
  "gcm.message_id" : "0: some number",
  "subtitle" : "www.someName.com",
  "smallIcon" : "small_icon",
  "largeIcon" : "large_icon",
  "title" : "Notification from ezzyr",
  "vibrate" : "1",
  "message" : "{\"action\":\"new_content_notification\",\"msg\":{\"headline\":\"iOS REFERRAL BONUS\",\"subhead\":\"Congratulations. You have unlocked another BDT500 discount on long route trip booking.\",\"brief\":\"Congratulations. You have unlocked another BDT500 discount on long route trip booking.\",\"content_id\":69}}",
  "sound" : "1",
  "tickerText" : "",
  "aps" : {
    "content-available" : "1"
  }
}
```

i want only data what i have in my message key. so i try to get message key value this way

```
let message = fullInfo["message"]
print(message)
```

after printing message i am getting this result

```
{"action":"new_content_notification","msg":{"headline":"iOS REFERRAL BONUS","subhead":"Congratulations. You have unlocked another BDT500 discount on long route trip booking.","brief":"Congratulations. You have unlocked another BDT500 discount on long route trip booking.","content_id":94}}
```

Than i was try to get the key value of "action" in this way.

```
let action = message["action"]
print(action)
```

but this time i am getting null value.. How can i fix this issue and get string value and also the key value of msg

Thanks advanced for help

Comment: The value of message is another JSON string. You have to deserialize it with `JSONSerialization` or `Decodable`, then you can access the keys and values.

Comment: how can i do that can please share some example

Comment: Please, questions about JSON serialization are one of the most frequently asked questions here on SO.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend ditching SwiftyJSON and JSONSerialization entirely, use `Codable` instead.

Use this to parse the inner JSON contained in `message`:

```
struct Message: Codable {
    let action: String
    let msg: Msg
}

struct Msg: Codable {
    let headline, subhead, brief: String
    let contentID: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case headline, subhead, brief
        case contentID = "content_id"
    }
}

if let messageStr = userInfo["message"] as? String {
  let messageData = messageStr.data(using: .utf8 )!
  let message = try JSONDecoder().decode(Message.self, from: messageData)
}
```

Comment: xcode complain Replace 'decoder' with 'decode .. after auto complete its says Cannot convert value of type '[AnyHashable : Any]' to expected argument type 'Data'

Comment: i am getting data from userinfo but when i pass this variable i gatting same error here i what pass, let fullInfo = try JSONDecoder().decode(FullInfo.self, from: userInfo)

Comment: it gives error "Cannot convert value of type '[AnyHashable : Any]' to expected argument type 'Data'"

Comment: Looks like you're passing the result of an initial  `JSONSerialization` call. Don't do that, pass the raw data to the decoder (ie. whatever you used to get to that dictionary.

Comment: i was updated my question hope it will help you to understand my problem..

Comment: So you're not getting JSON (except in the `message`), but rather a push notification. Updated my answer.

Comment: now getting this error Value of type '[AnyHashable : Any]' has no member 'message'

Answer (score 0):

As **vadian sir** have said, the value of the key **message** is another JSON string, so to get the value of **action** from **message**, you need 
to deserialize it with `JSONSerialization` like below and get the value of the key **action**.

```
let message = fullInfo["message"] as! String
let data = message.data(using: .utf8)!
do {
    if let messageDict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options : .allowFragments) as? [String : Any] {
        let action = messageDict["action"] as! String
        print(action)
    } else {
        print("bad json")
    }
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error)
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i getting error in runtime for bad execution in first line

Answer (score 0):

Check this : [Convert Json string to Json object in Swift 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47281375/convert-json-string-to-json-object-in-swift-4?rq=1)

Convert message text in json :

```
let messageStr = message as! String
let data = messageStr.data(using: .utf8)!
do {
    if let jsonArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options : .allowFragments) as? [Dictionary<String,Any>]
    {
       print(jsonArray) // use the json here    

        let action = jsonArray["action"]
        print(action) // your action is here

    } else {
        print("bad json")
    }
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: getting this error, Value of type 'JSON' has no member 'data' on first line

Comment: Please don't recommend using `JSONSerialization` when we have `Codable`