# how to append data in Mappable Class

Tags: ios, json, swift, objectmapper

I want to add new data to `Mappable` `class`. Here is my `class`:

```
import Foundation
import ObjectMapper

struct AllcategoriesModel : Mappable {
    var allcategories : [Allcategories]?

    init?(map: Map) {

    }

    mutating func mapping(map: Map) {
        allcategories <- map["allcategories"]
    }

}
```

The way I am adding new data to `class`:

```
if json["allcategories"].exists() {
    categoriesDataSource   = Mapper<AllcategoriesModel>().map(JSON: json.object as! [String : Any])
    //Other Stuff...
}
```

Now, I want to append data manually, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you want to append data in the allCategories variable ?

Comment: yes allCategories is modelclass

Comment: You can create an object of Allcategories and append it to the property.

Comment: you can append the element in the allCategories directly.

Comment: unable to append directly

Answer (score 1):

After initialisation of AllcategoriesModel struct object `categoriesDataSource`, you can append data to it just like you would do in any other object.

`categoriesDataSource.allcategories.append(newElement)`

Also, why did you leave the init?(map: Map) empty. It should initialize the allcategories array.

`allcategories = try? map.value("allcategories")`

Otherwise the `allcategories` will remain nil and thus your append method call won't work.

Comment: i dont understand your logic bro

Comment: After you initialize `categoriesDataSource   = Mapper<AllcategoriesModel>().map(JSON: json.object as! [String : Any])`, do you get a value in categoriesDataSource.allcategories or is it nil ?

Comment: yes i get values but after this i want to append some more data manually

Comment: Did you try `categoriesDataSource.allcategories.append(newElement)` ?

Comment: if another not understand 

this comment can adapt with this link

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47281375/convert-json-string-to-json-object-in-swift-4/47281832

you will can add data to Mappable object by jsonObject in same solution this answer